# Problems converting text input to numeric format with TfidfVectorizer of Sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I'm trying to train a model with Sklearn. In short, I have a Pandas Dataframe with two columns, the 'review' where I have the input (text format) and the 'sentiment' column, but I having trouble converting text input to numeric format with TfidfVectorizer of Sklearn.

With the following code:

```
  from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
  tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
  train_x_vector = tfidf.fit_transform(train_x)
  test_x_vector = tfidf.transform(test_x)


from sklearn.svm import SVC

svc = SVC(kernel='linear')
svc.fit(train_x_vector, train_y)
```

I get the following error:

[image]

I have the suspicion that the problem is in converting the input to numeric data:

[image]

Any suggestion to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi there. Please work through the guide on creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Copy all errors and code as text into the question, and reduce the amount of code to what is relevant to the problem. As written, there are some "red flags" in the code, like a `try/except` block around the `Tfidf` vectorizer.

Comment: take a look at the data stored in `train_x` which your code is passing to `tfidf.fit_transform(train_x)`. `train_x` should be a list of strings. if that looks okay, share the dataset too so this can be reproduced.

Comment: Tks, simpleApp! is correct in what you indicate. TfidfVectorizer expects a list or an array of strings as input. In the code, train_x is a DataFrame and not a list or an array of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TfidfVectorizer expects a list or an array of strings as input. In the code, train_x is a DataFrame and not a list or an array of strings.

Solution:

```
train_x_vector = tfidf.fit_transform(train_x['review'].values)
```